# How to make MiKTex portable? And the installation problem of the portable version of MiKTex

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9, miktex-update

Following the instruction on MiKTex website(see https://miktex.org/howto/portable-edition), Ｉ installed the latest portable version of MiKTex(basic-miktex-21.2-x64.exe) and it works well. Then I move the installed MiKTex folder into another place which cause everything changed, and the MiKtex can not work any more. This means it is not portable.
So, in my case, how to make the MiKTex portable that can be placed everywhere.
Thanks.

PS:
At the end of the potable version installation, a fault warning message is given(refer to the attachted figure). I wonder if it is because my operating system is `Windows 7`. Or does that mean the latest MiKTex dosen't support win7?

[image]

Comment: The idea of a "portable" distribution is that you have it on a USB stick which you can carry around, not that you can move the folder here and there and hope that it works.

Comment: Is there a way to make the MiKtex work after movingthe folder into a new place? It seems that "miktex-portable-2.9.6942" can do it, whereas the latest version can not.

Comment: As for USB stick, its disk letter may vary with different computer. In this case how can it be portable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested portable miktex 21.6 on my Windows 7. There was no problem with it. When you have changed the miktex folder, you need to run `miktex-portable.cmd` in the folder first. If you are using other TeX editors other than TeXworks, maybe you need to put a dos batch file with the following lines into miktex folder and run it:

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
echo Loading...
texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe --mkmaps
start "" path\to\you\editor.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

it exists on the Miktex site. I used it a few years ago.
The different packages must be correctly installed.

https://miktex.org/howto/portable-edition

A+

Comment: I had been following the instruction you mention in the link, and a fault message is given at the end of installation(please see the attached figure) . Why? And does that mean the latest version does not support `Windows 7`?